# Where is CONFIG_APM in kernel - 2.6.38.8

Tags: kernel, configuration

From here: http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-2.6/TROUBLESHOOTING

> Q: Which CONFIG_* items are latency killers, and should be avoided ?
>   ...
>   APM: The APM model assigns power management control to the BIOS, and
>   BIOS code is never written with RT-latency in mind.  If configured,
>   APM routines are invoked with SMI priority, which breaks the rule that
>   adeos-ipipe must be in charge of such things.  DISABLE_SMI doesnt help
>   here (more later).

**The problem is that I am not able to find this APM thing anywhere.**

[image]

[image]

**"ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) Support"**  results
in the following menu:

```
 --- ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) Support
[*]   Deprecated /proc/acpi files
[*]   Deprecated power /proc/acpi directories
 <M>   ACPI 4.0 power meter
 < >   EC read/write access through /sys/kernel/debug/ec (NEW)
[*]   Deprecated /proc/acpi/event support
<M>   AC Adapter
<M>   Battery
{M}   Button
{M}   Video
<M>   Fan
[*]   Dock
<M>   Processor
< >   IPMI (NEW)
<M>   Processor Aggregator
<M>   Thermal Zone
-*-   NUMA support
()    Custom DSDT
Table file to include
[*]   Debug Statements
[ ]   Additionally enable ACPI function tracing
<M>   PCI slot detection driver
{M}   Container and Module Devices (EXPERIMENTAL)
<M>   Memory Hotplug
<M>   Smart Battery System
< >   Hardware Error Device (NEW)
[ ]   ACPI Platform Error Interface (APEI) (NEW)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this option yourself:

Press `/` in the `menu menuconfig` interface , and put `CONFIG_APM` there , if you find anything , it's supported

I can only give you output from 3.3.7 version:

[image]

But anyway , you could edit the .config file yourself , and append `CONFIG_APM=y` , then redo `make menuconfig` ,

Comment: Actually, I am missing some point here. I am using "make menuconfig". That shows a GUI. This option isn't there in "Power management and ACPI support". I did attach the screenshot. what am I over looking?

Comment: @AnishaKaul if you're running this kernel already , can you show the output of `zgrep APM /proc/config.gz`

Comment: I am not running this kernel yet. I have to configure this first. :) I am kind of stuck here. :(

Comment: @AnishaKaul what about `grep APM .config` (inside kernel folder , provided you've saved your config)

Comment: I ran the command like this, didn't say anything: `linux-y3pi:/usr/src/linux-2.6.38.8 # grep APM .config
`

Comment: My fault, I didn't read the last statement of your answer. :doh: BTW, `Depends on: x86_32 [=n]` means what? By default the .config says that x86_32 is not set. So, should I set it to y? `CONFIG_APM=y` alone doesn't show the option. Do I have to restart the computer? :(

Comment: Damn my previous unwise comment about the grep command not working: `linux-y3pi:/usr/src/linux-2.6.38.8 # grep APM .config
CONFIG_APM=y
` That's fine, but make menuconfig GUI doesn't show anything APM.

Comment: does hardware matter in this case? Mine is `x86_64`

Comment: @AnishaKaul: depends on X86_32 means that option only exists for X86_32 configurations. If you're building an x86_64 kernel, APM isn't an option.

Comment: @Mat thanks, also, see my answer below. Seems that is relevant.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: no, it's not. You have that menu on SMP-enabled kernels for X86_32 as you do for UP systems.

Comment: @Mat I didn't understand your point completely. Please elaborate. what is UP?

Comment: UP is for single-cpu kernels (no SMP).

Comment: @Mat and I have not got your point. Pardon. Mine is a dual core system and the message says that APM is disabled on the dual cores. Is my understanding wrong. :newbie: